# Chrome not blocking invalid CORS request

Tags: cors

I am having a problem with a CORS request that I believe should be refused but which is being accepted by Chrome, Firefox and IE.  The request, from wireshark, is:

```
GET /postcode/rest/postcodeSearch?&provider=&postcode=PL6+7TL HTTP/1.1
Host: devtestl1:5706
Connection: keep-alive
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://localhost:5506
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1700.107 Safari/537.36
DNT: 1
Referer: http://localhost:5506/icm/admin/articles/dopreview.cfm?InEditorPreview=false&NodeID=1&Browser=NS6&HTMLEditor=TRUE&FlashTreePluginLocated=12&SubsiteName=&WYSIWYGEditControl=TEMPLATE&bMobileSimulator=False
Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch
Accept-Language: en,en-GB;q=0.8
```

The response is:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:5506
Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST
Access-Control-Max-Age: 60
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Content-Type,Authorization,X-Api-Session,X-Api-Key,X-Api-Token
Access-Control-Expose-Headers: Content-Type,X-Api-Session,X-Api-Token
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 669
Date: Tue, 18 Feb 2014 11:14:57 GMT
Connection: keep-alive

{"result":[{"udprn":"18994206","company":"Delta Engineering Plymouth LLP","department":"","line1":"Darklake View","line2":"Estover","line3":"","line4":"","line5":"","town":"Plymouth","county":"Devon","postcode":"PL6 7TL"},{"udprn":"18994215","company":"Goss Interactive Ltd","department":"","line1":"24 Darklake View","line2":"Estover","line3":"","line4":"","line5":"","town":"Plymouth","county":"Devon","postcode":"PL6 7TL"},{"udprn":"18994208","company":"Jennycrafts","department":"","line1":"Cranmere House","line2":"21 Darklake View","line3":"Estover","line4":"","line5":"","town":"Plymouth","county":"Devon","postcode":"PL6 7TL"}],"_transport_":{"statusCode":200}}
```

The returned postcode data is being displayed in the browser even though a GET request is responded with the "Access-Control-Allow-Method: POST" header.
As I understand it the browser should discard the entire response.

Why is this response permitted?

Thanks,
Andy

Comment: How was the request initiated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I see the problem now.  The Access-Control-Allow-Method header is only used with an OPTIONS pre-flight message.  It seems that the decision to reject the request on the basis of the method should be made at the server.  The same also applies to the Access-Control-Allow-Headers header.

Comment: That is right. Since your request is a GET request without any custom headers, there is no preflight request. Your server should guard against these types of requests. Note that someone can make a GET request across domains without using CORS, for example, with the img or src tags.